# Play Scala 2.6 with Ebean : accessing an Entity field makes OneToMany associations empty

Tags: scala, ebean, playframework-2.6

I have a OneToMany in my model, I would like (if possible) to access the field without query.  Or at least, understand why the list is empty in some cases

```
@Entity
class Product extends Model {

  @Id
  var id : Long = -1

  @Column
  var price : Float = _

  @Column
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  var productImages : java.util.List[ProductImage] = _


  @Column
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  var categoryProduct : java.util.List[CategoryProduct] = _

}
```

and

```
@Entity
class ProductImage extends Model {

  @ManyToOne
  var product : Product = _

  @Column
  var id : Long = _

}
```

In my scala template, I can `@product.productImages.get(0)`, it works.

But if I access another field in the template like `@product.price` then `product.productImages` is generally an empty list, (some products, 1 or 2 about 20, get their images)

Why do the  fetching of association depends on accessing other fields of the entity ?
Why some product still fetch their images ?

PS : I found out that the association is fetched when I query this way :

```
CategoryProduct.find.query().where().eq("category", cat).setMaxRows(5).findList.asScala.toList
  .map {_.product}
```

Not when I query products directly like this : `Product.find.query().setMaxRows(20).findList.asScala.toList`

Answer (score 0):

It's explained here :
https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/1381

I need to add an @Id field to my child beans.